# scribe sample for custom oAuth provider

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, scribe

I have my own oAuth 2.0 authorization server and resource (API) server. The client will be Android apps. I'm looking for a scribe sample that works against a custom oAuth provider. Is scribe the best option available for doing oAuth from Android client apps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find your answer in another stackoverflow response:

[Android & OAUTH 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215557/android-oauth-2-0)

Answer (score -1):

Scribe requires various end points that people don't normally use. If you have the end points configured then yes Scribe is the best.